# Sharing a common function: how do I trigger a subclass action?

Tags: generics, swift3, overriding

I want to make the following specific function (SatellitesViewController):

[image]

...into a more-generic function (type: UIViewController):
[image]

**Problem:** converting the UIViewerController back to the source UIViewController child type so I can send an action back to the calling source.

I'm getting the compiler error that 'UIViewController' doesn't have such a function; which is true.   However checking the calling source (sender)'s type reveals the true type (which has the function):

```
(lldb) po type(of: sender)
SwiftTech.SatellitesViewController
```

The sender is 'UIViewController' when it should be 'SatellitesViewController':

[image]

**Question:** how do I force the sender parameter's type to its *true* type vs the generic UIViewController?

Is this a typical Swift-generic scenario?

---

**Solution Attempt:**

The **generic** route doesn't appear to be the solution here. 
So, I thought I could add abstract button actions to the UIViewController parent to satisfy the callback:

[image]

... then override the functions in the children UIViewControllers (e.g. the 'SatellitesViewController' like so:

```
extension SatellitesViewController {

    override func displayGrayOverview() {
        let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDownSwipe))
        swipeGesture.direction = .down
        self.grayOverview.positionOverLay(sender:self, parentView: self.view)
        self.grayOverview.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
    }
...
}
```

But this only fires the UIViewController's function; *not the inherited* (override) function of its child.

```
***UIController's Button Action ***
```

I prefer to have the implementation handled in the *child* UIViewController instead of within the UIViewController class itself; or not handled at all...as with other descendants of the UIViewController.

So it boils down to: assuming I'm on the right track here, how do I force the **override** functions() to fire vs the parent functions()?

---

Here's the code per request:

The host requesting the gray-overlay view:

```
extension SatellitesViewController {

    func displayGrayOverview() {
        let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDownSwipe))
        swipeGesture.direction = .down
        self.grayOverview.positionNetworkSatOverLay(sender:self, parentView: self.view)
        self.grayOverview.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func showCode(completion:@escaping BasicCallBack) {
        if Bundle.main.url(forResource:"NetworkSatellites", withExtension: "pdf") != nil {
            let preview = QLPreviewController()
            preview.dataSource = self
            preview.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0

            self.present(preview, animated: true, completion: { 
                completion()
            })
        }
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: - Selector handlers

    func handleDownSwipe() {
        grayOverview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: - Handle Swipe Gesture

    func handleButtonAction(sender:UIButton) {
        showCode() {completion in
            self.grayOverview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @IBAction func infoAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
       displayGrayOverview()
    }
}
```

Here's the called function that I wish to make available to ALL **sender**s of type **UIViewController** vs : **SatellitesViewController** :

```
extension UIView {
  final func positionNetworkSatOverLay(sender:SatellitesViewController,
                                   parentView:UIView,
                                   overlayColor:UIColor = UIColor.overlayGray) {
        self.backgroundColor = overlayColor
        let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.frame = screenBounds
        self.tag = 201

        var buttonTitles:NSArray?
        guard let navButtonURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "NetworkInfo", withExtension: "plist") else {
            return
        }

        buttonTitles = NSArray(contentsOf: navButtonURL)

        let myButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        myButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 32.0)
        myButton.setTitle(String(describing: buttonTitles![0]), for: .normal)
        myButton.sizeToFit()

        self.addSubview(myButton)
        myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let viewDictionary:Dictionary = ["subView": myButton]
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(x)-[subView(==w)]", options: [], metrics: ["x":200.0, "w":myButton.frame.size.width], views: viewDictionary))

        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(y)-[subView(==h)]", options: [], metrics: ["y":400.0,"h":myButton.frame.size.height], views: viewDictionary))


        myButton.addTarget(sender, action: #selector(sender.handleButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)


        parentView.addSubview(self)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please post code instead of images.

Comment: I've added the source code per request.